# Is there any security risk if "blogger id" is public?

Tags: api, security, blogger, blogspot

I would like to use my "blogger id" in javascript program.Is there any security risk if my "blogger id" is known to other people?

Answer (score 0):

If you can hack a facebook profile with it's id only or a G+ profile with only it's Id 
then there can be some issue with your blogger id :D

simply "NO"